# Python skipping for-loop after print()

Tags: python, for-loop, python-itertools

I'm at debugging part of writing my code, so I'm using lots of calls to `print` to check the values of my variables. I have encountered a situation, when printing a variable causes Python to skip a `for` loop.

```
import numpy as np
import itertools as itr
(...)

class myclass():
    def a_function_inside_a_class():
        print('-------------')
        current_size = self.get_current_size()
        current_size[dimension] += 1

        new_layer = [range(i) for i in current_size]
        new_layer[dimension] = [current_size[dimension]]
        print(new_layer)

        new_layer = itr.product(*new_layer)
        print(list(new_layer)) # THIS LINE CAUSES PROBLEMS

        for c in new_layer:
            print('for')
            print(list(c))
            (...)
            a_function_that_causes_some_error(c)
```

I create a list, then use `itertools` to create combinations of this list and then iterate over them. 
If I call the `a_function_inside_a_class()` as it is above, **I don't get the `for` printed. No error occurs.** The interpreter does not enter the loop.

```
(...)
-------------
[[2], range(0, 1), range(0, 1)]
[(2, 0, 0)]
-------------
[range(0, 1), [2], range(0, 1)]
[(0, 2, 0)]
(...)
```

But if I **comment out `#print(list(new_layer))`** then the for-loop is executed and I get an error caused by some other function `a_function_that_causes_some_error(c)`.

```
-------------
[[2], range(0, 1), range(0, 1)]
for
[2, 0, 0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
(...)
```

The `list(new_layer)` does not change the `new_layer` object itself, only creates a list and passes it to `print()` function, does it?

Comment: how exactly are you calling `a_function_inside_a_class`?

Comment: Maybe new_layer has been "read" when you call list(new_layer) so it is empty for the loop.

Comment: and why is there a `self` inside the body of the function but not in the argument list of the function?

Comment: Just put another ``print(list(new_layer))`` in the line following the first call and you'll see why it fails.

Comment: The `print` is not the problem, the `list()` is.  `itertools.product()` is a generator, when you use `list()` on it you have exhausted the iterator.  Do a `for` on the list instead.

Comment: @cdarke - You spoiled it! I wanted to hint at this fact without giving it away. But you are exactly right! :-)

Comment: @MSeifert:  was checking my comment with the doc as I was writing it, so I missed yours.  Sorry to spoil your fun!

Comment: most of the code is dummy (thus some minor defects like no `self` in function definition)

now I got it, didn't know anything about generators! thanks!

Comment: @Fidd for future questions: it is better to provide a minimal version that actually runs, i.e. which people can paste into their interpreter to look for the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `itertools.product` returns a generator.

When you call `print(list(new_layer))` you are constructing a list from the generator, but don't save a reference to that list anywhere.

The generator itself will be exhausted after converting it to a list, because `list(some_generator)` calls `__next__` (or `next`, depending on Python version) on that generator until it raises `StopIteration`.

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> new_layer = product([1,2,3], [4,5,6])
>>> new_layer
<itertools.product object at 0x7f46e90349b0>
>>> print(list(new_layer))
[(1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6)]
>>> print(list(new_layer))
[]
```

As you can see, after constructing the list *once*, the generator is empty.

You can fix your program by using

```
new_layer = list(itr.product(*new_layer))
print(new_layer)
```

because now you will have a reference to the list you are creating from the generator.

Comment: Your suggestion works but it totally contradicts the use of ``itertools`` in his case because you save the result where one should only keep the generator. The lesson here should be: Don't debug the loop-variable before looping, debug/show them inside the loop

Comment: @MSeifert yes, as far as I understand OP, he is using the calls to print for debugging. I would suggest to use my fix until the program is properly tested. Then, after removing the print statements, converting the generator to a list is no longer necessary and the program will be more memory efficient if you just use the generator as is.